# Access another network computer, after remoting into this one from outside?

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop, firewall, jenkins

I have a Jenkins instance running on machine-A.

On machine-B, I can go type the IP:port of machine-A into my browser, and access it just fine.

Machines A & B share a local network, behind a firewall.

On machine-C (outside the network & firewall), I can remote into machine-B using RDP. I can access that network's firewalled email & messenger no problem. But I cant reach machine-A's IP anymore.

What configuration on any of these machines needs to change, so that I can access the Jenkins instance on machine-A from machine-C?

I cant make changes to the firewall/ports surrounding A & B.

I cant RDP directly from C > A, because B&C are windows, A is Mac, and my RDP software only works for windows.

Comment: If you're RDPing (as in, using Microsoft's RDP) into B, then you are using B.  If it works when you're sitting in front of B, then it should work EXACTLY the same when RDP'ing in, and there should be nothing stopping you from accessing A from B.  When you went back to work, and went back to sitting at B, could you then access A?

Comment: I agree, ping it.  Do you have a router ? Can you browse the router's web interface ?